# camel ahc ignoring query parameters

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to set up a route for ahc

My requirements:

- the target http(s) url is passed as a previous header/property
- I have cases where `throwExceptionOnFailure` needs to be set to true and others to false.
- I want that query parameters passed in to my route remain forwarded to the target.

I am setting the properties previous in other routes as follows:

```
// sample path for this case. this is built based on other factors
String basePath = "http://my.service:8080/test/api/dir"
//...
.setHeader(HEADER_FOR_ROUTE_PATH, constant(basePath))
.setHeader(HEADER_FOR_THROW_EXCEPTION, declaration.is4xxResponseCodeAllowed() ? constant("false") : constant("true")
```

and I have tried the following routes to try to handle this:

```
   from("direct:myroute")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${header.%s}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=${header.%s}".formatted(HEADER_FOR_ROUTE_PATH, HEADER_FOR_THROW_EXCEPTION)
        .to("ahc:http://oldhost");
```

```
   from("direct:myroute")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${header.%s}".formatted(HEADER_FOR_ROUTE_PATH)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=${header.%s}"formatted(HEADER_FOR_THROW_EXCEPTION))
        .to("ahc:http://oldhost");
```

(and in this case the throwsExceptionOnFailure is hardcoded but i created separate routes to distinguish this.

```
   from("direct:myroute")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${header.%s}".formatted(HEADER_FOR_ROUTE_PATH)
        .to("ahc:http://oldhost?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

and all seem to have some issues amongst:

- Source query parameters not forwarded
- bridgeEndpoint / throwExceptionOnFailure being ignored (so it tries to go to "oldhost" rather than "my.service"

How can i get this scenario to work please as I'm struggling to find any information on how i can set this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as follows:

```
 from("direct:myroute")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${header.%s}".formatted(HEADER_FOR_ROUTE_PATH)
        .to("ahc:http://oldhost?bridgeEndpoint=false&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

since in this case the HTTP_URI is ovverriden, the bridgeEndpoint flag should be false